# Pandas Dataframe very slow while adding rows having object dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add in 55k rows in a loop to a dataframe using `loc`. The first column is of `object type` and adding 55k rows taking many minutes. If I change the column and keep some `int` value, then the rows get filled with in seconds.

```
dfreglist.loc[dfreglistrow] = [rows[0],0, 0, intdisti, intres, intbus, intsite, 1]
```

I couldn't convert `dtype` of object to category as all 55k values of this column is unique.

Is there anyway, I can have a solution for the same.

Comment: How about first creating a dataframe of 55k rows and then appending it to the original dataframe?

Comment: The answer here is "don't". Use a regular list and construct a DataFrame from that list once it's full (after loop is finished).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I used iat to update each column and whole 55k rows updated in couple of seconds. iat is very fast comparing to row updates having object dtype it seems.